# jquery selector for menu wp li ul

Tags: jquery, menu, html-lists

Im tryin to make some jquery in a menu with wordpress generated li ul structure. I want to select the first row of li and not the nested one (id like to do something diff with them) but i keep firing the nested ones aswell.. weird thing is that it does work for only giving a border to the li's with an ul. (and the last nested li's have no ul in there..)
i tried using .has selector, parent>child but none worked.

```
  $('#hmenu li ul').parent().mouseenter( function() {
        $('#hmenu li ul').hide();
                    $(this.children).slideDown('fast').css({ color: 'red'});
                    alert('bingo!');
            stopPropagation();
  });

  <div id="hmenu">
      <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_order=desc'); ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is a bit confusing. Have you ever tried [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

You should write your sample code there and post a link to it here, so everyone can figure out what you mean. Please, try to make clear which elements you want to select and what operations you would like to perform on them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understand your question right - but here is a way to select only the `<li>`-items containing a `<ul>`-Element.

```
   $("#hmenu ul li").find("ul").parent().doWhateverYouWantWithThisElement();
```

the explanation:

select all `<li>` within the `<ul>` of the `#hmenu`-container then looking for an `<ul>`-element in those `<li>`'s when found go back to parent and now do what you need to do.

I've made a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fma94/ to explain this way.